# ATBS Regex Search Project-How to solve local scope error?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I've been working through the book ATBS with Python and I have a question about the Chapter 8 project "Regex Search". It asks you to create a program that opens all ".txt" files in a folder and searches for any line that matches a user-supplied regular expression. The results should then be printed to the screen. I am running this on Visual Studio Code in Python version 3.9 for reference.

Here is my code:

```
    import os, re

    def Input_Folder(): 
        Search_Folder=input('Please provide a folder path:')
        FileList=os.listdir(Search_Folder)
        Search_Regex=input('Please provide a regex to search for:')
        RegexCompile=re.compile(Search_Regex)
    
    for file in FileList: 
        if file.endswith('.txt') in FileList: 
            Result_txt=os.listdir(file)
        print(Result_txt)

    for txt_files in Result_txt: 
        count=0
        with open(txt_files, 'r') as f: 
        txt_filecontent=f.read()
        match=re.search(RegexCompile, txt_filecontent)
        if match:
            count+=1
        print('There were '+str(count)+'matches of your regex found.')

    Input_Folder()
```

The error that appears looks like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/myname/Documents/RegexSearchChp8OriginalTry.py", line 27, 
    in <module>
          Input_Folder() 
      File "/Users/myname/Documents/RegexSearchChp8OriginalTry.py", line 16, 
    in Input_Folder print(Result_txt)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Result_txt' referenced before assignment
```

Looking at the error message, it looks like the variable "Result_txt" is a local variable and the following for loop "for txt_files in Result_txt:" cannot access it. However, I'm not really sure how to proceed since other examples that I've looked at where the code is all under one function have had bugs as well.

I used /Users/myname/Documents/ as the folder path when asked if that helps at all. I apologize since this was a long post but I appreciate any suggestions or advice. Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: Please check the whitespace in your example code, because in python the indentation matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Result_text as a global variable instead of local variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your for `FileList` loop. If your if condition is false, you will not declare the variable `Result_txt` which you want to print.
This leads to the error you see.